# How to run teradata scripts in AWS EC2 Teradata Database developer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, teradata

I have launched Teradata Database Developer -Single Node--15 from Amazon AWS.
I have successfully logged into the instance from putty.
AWS instance is 12.xlarge

I am not able to write teradata scripts in the console. I am not sure how to create database or like what should be the next step after this? Right now I screen like this

ip-144-41-55-72:~ #

Comment: Is the database service running? Have you attempted to create any ODBC or JDBC connections etc?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Teradata Studio to connect to the newly launched Teradata instance.

Here is the documentation related to setting up Teradata Studio -> https://aws.docs.teradata.com/aat1472159519086.html